# Remove label before I click in java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

ı have problem about delete a empty string values like we can see in picture,
in the first time if here is empty he give a error but after that even we write some strings in that blank,its still giving the same error how can ı delete this label before the sending again[image] [image] How can ı fix that problem ı tried some codes but nothing worked well please help about that

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class ui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        uiVision();
    }
    public static void uiVision() {
        ImageIcon eyes = new ImageIcon("a.png");
        Globals.jf.setTitle("Deneme Uygulamasi");
        Globals.jf.setLocation(100,200);
        JLabel label1,label2,label3;
        Globals.jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTextField isim = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField soyisim = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField pasaport = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField mail = new JTextField(20);
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        JPasswordField passwordField2 = new JPasswordField(10);



        JButton buton1 = new JButton("Send");
        JButton buton2 = new JButton(eyes);
        JButton buton3 = new JButton(eyes);
        JButton buton4 = new JButton("!");

        label1 = new JLabel("Name:");// -8
        label2 = new JLabel("Surname:");// -9
        label3 = new JLabel("Passaport-ID:");//+ 10
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Mail:");// +10
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Password:");//+10
        JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Re-Password:");// +20

        buton1.setBounds(170,400,150,30);
        buton2.setBounds(320,190,50,30);
        buton3.setBounds(320,230,50,30);
        buton4.setBounds(370,230,50,30);

        isim.setBounds(170,30,150,30);
        soyisim.setBounds(170,70,150,30);
        pasaport.setBounds(170,110,150,30);
        mail.setBounds(170,150,150,30);
        passwordField.setBounds(170,190,150,30);
        passwordField2.setBounds(170,230,150,30);



        label1.setBounds(125,30,150,30);
        label2.setBounds(106,70,150,30);
        label3.setBounds(90,110,150,30);
        label4.setBounds(132,150,150,30);
        label5.setBounds(105,190,150,30);
        label6.setBounds(91,230,150,30);

        Globals.jf.add(buton1);Globals.jf.add(buton2);Globals.jf.add(buton3);
        Globals.jf.add(label1);Globals.jf.add(label2);Globals.jf.add(label3);Globals.jf.add(label4); Globals.jf.add(label5);Globals.jf.add(label6);
        Globals.jf.add(isim);Globals.jf.add(soyisim);Globals.jf.add(pasaport);Globals.jf.add(mail);Globals.jf.add(passwordField);Globals.jf.add(passwordField2);
        Globals.jf.setSize(1000,500);



        buton2.addActionListener(l -> {
            if ( passwordField.getEchoChar() != '\u0000' ) {
                passwordField.setEchoChar('\u0000');
            } else {
                passwordField.setEchoChar((Character) UIManager.get("PasswordField.echoChar"));
            }
        });

        buton3.addActionListener(l -> {
            if ( passwordField2.getEchoChar() != '\u0000' ) {
                passwordField2.setEchoChar('\u0000');

            } else {
                passwordField2.setEchoChar((Character) UIManager.get("PasswordField.echoChar"));
            }
        });
        buton1.addActionListener(e -> {
            checkEmpty(isim.getText(),label1.getText(),label1);
            checkEmpty(soyisim.getText(),label2.getText(),label2);
            checkEmpty(pasaport.getText(),label3.getText(),label3);
            checkEmpty(mail.getText(),label4.getText(),label4);
            ExitWhenLoopEnd();
            Globals.globalInt = 0;
            System.out.println(passwordField.getPassword());
            System.out.println(passwordField2.getPassword());
            Globals.clickCount++;

        });
        Globals.jf.setLayout(null);
        Globals.jf.setVisible(true);
        Globals.jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void checkEmpty(String value,String label,JLabel labelname) {
        Integer syc = Integer.valueOf(0);

        if(value != null && !value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            if(Globals.globalInt != 4) {
                Globals.globalInt++;
            }
            syc = 1;
        }
        else {
            
            CreateEmptyMessageError(label,labelname,Globals.jf);
            syc = -1;
        }


        System.out.println(syc);

    }

    public static void CreateEmptyMessageError(String labelError,JLabel label,JFrame jf) {
        Globals.labelx = new JLabel(labelError.split(":")[0]+" is empty!");
        Globals.labelx.setBounds(label.getBounds().x+250,label.getBounds().y,label.getWidth(),label.getHeight());
        Globals.labelx.setForeground(Color.RED);
        jf.add(Globals.labelx);
        jf.revalidate();
        jf.repaint();

    }
    public class Globals {
        public static int globalInt = 0;
        public static JLabel labelx = null;
        public static JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        public static int clickCount = 0;
        public static int lastVal = 0;
        public static int syc = 0;


    }

    public static void ExitWhenLoopEnd() {
        if(Globals.globalInt == 4)  {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is usually not advisable to use global variables. Try to not use `static` fields unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Also, this, `Globals.jf.setLayout(null);`, and all those `.setBounds` are not a good idea. Also, give your variables better names, names that are descriptive, making your code self-commenting.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What can ı use for .setBounds functions

Comment: You'll want to use the layout managers. You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating a new JLabel and adding it to the GUI each time `CreateEmptyMessageError(...)` is called, and by doing this, you have no reference to this object, and no way to change its state.

The solution is to not do this, to instead create the error message label when you create the GUI itself, assign it to an instance field, and in that method above to not create a new JLabel object but rather to set the text of the existing object, one that shows a warning if the JTextField is empty, and one that sets the JLabel text to the empty String, `""`, if the JTextField has text.

Also,

- As Progman has suggested in comments, avoid the use of static fields and methods unless the use suggests that these should be used, and this isn't the case here. Instead, use private *instance* fields and methods. This will make your code easier to mock/test/extend and re-use, this reduces potential for hard to identify bugs by reducing your code's cyclomatic complexity and coupling.
- Avoid the use of null layouts and `setBounds(...)` and instead learn and use the layout managers.
- Learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.
- Give your fields names that describe what they represent, making your code self-commenting and easier to understand.